# add duplicate value for primary key

Tags: mysql, insert, key, duplicates

I have a table  with fields (id , brand, model , os) 
id as primary key

tables have  ~ 6000 rows

Now i want to add new field with id=4012 (already exist) & increment id++ for id>4012

silliest way :

1. make table backup
2. remove entries with id >= 4012
3. insert new entry with  id = 4012
4. restore table from backup

stupid, but works ))

Looking for more beautiful solution 
Thx

table structure :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mobileslist` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `brand` text NOT NULL,
  `model` text NOT NULL,
  `os` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=14823 ;
```

i try :

> UPDATE mobileslist SET     id = id + 1 WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM
>   mobileslist WHERE id >= 4822 ORDER BY id);

but got answer :

> 1093 - You can't specify target table 'mobileslist' for update in FROM clause

Comment: Why do you need to to this instead of using the default primary key value?

Comment: This just sounds like a bad database design. Can you give us more background.

Comment: just need insert new entry with fixed position

Comment: for group  models (compact) of one brand

Answer (score 0):

Hope i understood it right, you want to insert a new entry at position 4012 moving & reassigning all the entries present at Id = 4012 or more with a new id incremented by 1.
Hope this helps.

Try this:

```
UPDATE <TableName>
SET 
    id = id + 1
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM <TableName> WHERE id >= 4012 ORDER BY id)

INSERT INTO <TableName>
    (id , brand, model , os)
VALUE
    (4012, "<BrandName>", "<Model>", "<OS>")
```

Updated Answer:

```
DECLARE @MaxId INT, @Difference INT
SELECT
    @MaxId = MAX(id)
FROM mobileslist

SET @Difference = @MaxId - 4012

UPDATE mobileslist
SET
id = id + @Difference
where id >= 4012

INSERT INTO mobileslist
    (id , brand, model , os)
VALUE
    (4012, "TestBrand", "TestModel", "TestOS")

UPDATE mobileslist
SET
id = id - @Difference
where id > 4012
```

Comment: #1062 - Duplicate entry '4013' for key 'PRIMARY'

Comment: #1093 - You can't specify target table 'mobileslist' for update in FROM clause

Answer (score 0):

1) Create a temporary table, with descending order by ID.
2) Perform an UPDATE query on the temporary table which sets ID = ID + 1 WHERE ID >= 4012
3) Drop the temporary table
4) Perform your insert operation on the original table.